# Attach a frida on a paused app startup (waiting for debug)

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

I'm try to attach a frida script to a paused process on an Android emulator.
I followed those steps:

- Android EMU: ro.debuggable=1
- Android EMU: on developer options I set "Waiting for debugger" and select my app on "Select app for debug" list
- Create a frida script where I just call console.log("Attached to process")
- Start AndroidStudio 3.1 and Attach to a process (via ADB)

Well, I start the frida script, the app spawn and wait for a debugger attach, then I attach to it with Android Studio.
I attach successful with Android Studio but frida script remain freezed without showing the message on console.

It's a problem on android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found a bug with Frida + Android Emulator.

Comment: Did you find any solution to tihs?